# Unity: Physics.BoxCast always returning false, when it's supposed to be true (while BoxCastAll always gives hits,length > 0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I have a bug that i can't understand, and it doesn't seems like i am responsible for that bug... So I'll try my luck here, maybe someone can help me know the problem.

Unity version: 2021.3.21f1

What I know:

- BoxCast returns true if there is at least one collision in that Box (which is, in my situation, a box between the future position of GameObject A and B)
- BoxCastAll returns all the collisions in that Box.
- BoxCast AND BoxCastAll has exactly the same parameters for the same purpose.
- So if BoxCastAll hits > 0 then BoxCast = true (that's supposed to be the case)
- BoxCastAll Works exactly like what i want and returns all gameObjects that I as expected.
- I used Gizmo to verify the position of Box, and verify all my tests and positions.
- THE PROBLEM HERE: BoxCast ALWAYS RETURN FALSE. Why ? (I have been stuck for hours before understanding that BoxCast was maybe the bug... at least BoxCastAll tells me that my code is right...)
- My assumption : For an unknown reason, this BoxCast is bugged (which is normally... impossible...), or I have a bug somewhere in my code which would make BoxCastAll works and not BoxCast (which is also very weird...). I decided to go on another route to not be stuck but i'd still like to know the problem.

  ```
   private bool HasCollisionBetween(Vector3 _nextMobPosition) 
   {
    Vector3 nextMobPosition = _nextMobPosition;
    Vector3 direction = _nextMobPosition - nextSquadDestination;
    float distance = direction.magnitude;

    // Calculate the center position of the box
    Vector3 centerPos = nextSquadDestination + (direction / 2f) + heightOffset;

    // Calculate the orientation of the box based on the direction vector
    Quaternion orientation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

    Vector3 halfExtents = new Vector3(lineWidth / 2f, lineWidth / 2f, (distance - 2) / 2f);
    bool hasCollision = Physics.BoxCast(centerPos, halfExtents, direction, orientation, distance, undestructibleLayer);
    RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.BoxCastAll(centerPos, halfExtents, direction, orientation, distance, undestructibleLayer);

    // Check if there are any hits in the array
    if (hits.Length > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Something is between object 1 and object 2! " + hits[0].transform.name + " &&& hits : " + hits.Length);
    }

    Debug.Log("hasCollision : " + hasCollision);
    return hasCollision;
   }
  ```

I don't think I need to say it but I obviously have hits.Length > 1 AND hasCollision = false. And I did many tests which was always the same answer => BoxCastAll always gave me my expected answer while BoxCast always false.

Is there a Unity god who knows the reason ?